# SQL Views Multiple Line Entries

Tags: sql-server, join, multiple-columns

I have an interesting one that I have searched for and can't find the solution to.

I am working with a developer who is trying to integrate our incident management tool into Palladium, a finance tool and we're stuck on being able to import invoices correctly.

Scenario
There is a view that contains the invoices but there's several elements to the invoice. The view here shows all the billing parts and includes value amounts for Products and Expenses but it doesn't show details of the products or expenses as there may be multiple line items in that invoice. There are 2 further views one containing the product information and one containing the expense information. There is a common field that can be used to reference the invoice in each of these views called Billing_Log_RecID.

Here's how the default invoice search view looks when exported. I've selected entries where there are products and/or expenses added.

[image]

What I need to do is display in a view a line item for each invoice but break out the multiple expense or product items into I guess separate columns so for example

Inv1 COMPANYNAME COMPANYID INVTOT PROD1 PVAL1 PROD2 PVAL2 etc EXP1 EVAL1 EXP2 EVAL2 etc, there's never likely to be more then 2-3 different items but to be safe 5 is a good number.

Here's an example of a query showing products attached to an invoice, I have highlighted where there are multiple lines.

[image]

The same exists for the expense items

[image]

Hope someone can help.
Dave

Comment: Instead of images if you are able to provide input table structure and output structure will be helpful

Comment: Hi Kannan, are you wanting to see the query behind the view showing where the data originates?

Comment: Hi all, anyone able to offer any advice?

Comment: Morning all, still struggling with this, any help/advice gratefully appreciated